# want to refresh chats at both users' side

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script which fetch the chats and refresh it at both the users side so that looks real time for both the users who are chatting. But the problm is that when I pull the scroll bar to the bottom(as most of the chatting application do) at the begining the setTimeout function reload the chats and it prevents the user to scroll up the bar.

```
        <script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
     chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time 
             $('#messages').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight
                }, 800);

    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {

    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    //immediately fetch chat for the new ID, and clear any waiting fetch timer that might be pending
    clearTimeout(chatTimer);
    fetch_chat(); 
  });

  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();

    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
      $('#messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
    });
  });

  fetch_data();//this will also trigger the first fetch_chat once it completes
});
</script>
```

I want the scroll bar to be at the bottom but should be scrollable without any harm to the code that refreshed the messages div.

Answer (score 0):

try to not reload all the chat but adding the new Massage Every time or
make sure to save an unkoer  of the postponing of the reader

Comment: `code`
function loadNewMassge(){
//ajax that load that new Massges
return str;
}

var last_id=000;
$("#idoflastmasge"+last_id).after(loadNewMassge());
last_id++;